# An issue with most occurring elements in JS array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to display list with words for autocompleting:

```js
var words = ['foo', 'bar', 'barz', 'ba'];
var possibleWords = [];
  
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(){
      
  var textWords = this.innerText.split(' ');
  var lastWord = textWords[textWords.length-1];
  for(var k = 0; k < words.length; k++){
      
    for(n = 0; n < 20; n++){
          
      if(lastWord.length == n+1 && words[k].charAt(n) == lastWord.charAt(n)){
        possibleWords.push(words[k]);
            
        var counts = possibleWords.reduce((a, c) => {
          a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
          return a;
        }, {});
        var maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(counts));
        var mostFrequent = Object.keys(counts).filter(k => counts[k] === maxCount);
      }
    }
  }
      
  console.log(mostFrequent);
      
  var list = this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  if(mostFrequent == undefined) {
    list.removeAttribute('style');
  } else {
      
    list.style.display = 'inline';
    list.innerHTML = '';
    list.innerHTML = '<li>'+mostFrequent.join('</li><li>')+'</li>';
  }
});
```

```css
div{
width:300px;
height:100px;
outline:1px solid #ccc;
position:relative;
}
ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><ul></ul></div>
```

When I comment the bottom code from `var list = ...` to `list.innerHTML = '<li>'+...` and try to type **b**, then **ba**, then **bar** and then **barz** I see correct result in the console. But if I don't comment the bottom code, I receive `undefined` half the time and the list is also hidden half the time.

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this odd behavior because your `<ul>` tag that you dynamically update is nested within the same `div` that receives input to feed the contents of the list. Consider what the value of `this.innerText` is on your div `keyup` listener after you dynamically modify the list that the div contains.

Try `console.log(textWords)` at the top of your keyUp listener to see.

Simply making your div this instead:

`<div contenteditable="true"></div><ul></ul>`

and changing the listener near the end of your snippet to

`var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];`

Solved the issue for me.

As an aside -- there are more performant ways to implement autocomplete. Look into "autocomplete trie" for just one way.